# Mongodb 2.6 Packages Removed from Mongo Repo?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt-get, repository, mongodb

I am attempting to build Mongodb 2.6.7 from the Mongo repos and am now unable to download them, as I was able to last week...

```
root@591d529e0497:/# echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
root@591d529e0497:/# apt-get update
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Get:1 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease [169 kB]
Err:1 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Fetched 169 kB in 1s (122 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Does anyone know where I could get these packages from a legitimate source? Or is Mongodb just having a bad day?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB 2.6 reached End of Life (EOL)](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life) back in Oct 2016. The `downloads-distro.mongodb.org` server which hosted pre-3.0 MongoDB server packages was retired in August, 2019.

The 2.6 MongoDB server release series started in March, 2014 and is definitely no longer recommended for development or production use. There are known security and stability issues that have been addressed in subsequent releases, and the signatures for the older packages have expired.

You can still download release tarballs from https://www.mongodb.org/dl/linux/x86_64, but I'd strongly recommend upgrading to a modern and supported version of MongoDB.